# How to make the background color fill the screen

Tags: html

my background color only seems to be filling half the screen... is their a way to get it to fill all of the screen? code below:

```
<div data-role="page" id="carbcounter" data-theme = "a"> 

<div data-role="header">
<h1>The Carb Counter</h1>
```

Only half off the screen is colored grey with the set color of data-theme -a ?

Comment: _code below:..._ Wondering how this "code" is doing any type of coloring at all

Comment: Show the code which sets the background color

Comment: I assume it might have something to do with jquery mobile?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56131383/edit) then the `[<>]` stacksnippet editor and add relevant script and CSS.

Comment: how is the data-theme defined? Can you give more details about that? It may be the issue

Answer (score -1):

Since you are tagging it as html then you would use css for styling.

```
html{
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the `Only half off the screen is colored grey with the set color of data-theme -a`